# python-rrdtool try except rrdtool.error module object has no attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code that gives this error on Linux and will be grateful if you can help

```
import rrdtool

try:      
      ret_asd = rrdtool.update(myfile.rrd,'N:%s:%s' %(metric1, metric2));    
except rrdtool.error, e:
      print e
```

When i run the above i get the below error

```
except rrdtool.error, e:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Appreciate if you can help me get a solution for this

Thanks